# Why is Google Cloud Platform cron firing off jobs an hour early?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've scheduled a cron job on Google Cloud Platform to execute each morning at 09:15 EST. Here is the schedule screenshot.

[image]

It shows the last run at 08:15:00. I assumed that because I was viewing this in CST things were okay--but it appears that the last run time was 08:15:00 ***EST***. I confirmed by looking at the log entry shown below:

[image]

UPDATE: cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: Start Trading Scheduler
  target: worker
  url: /startup_trading_scheduler
  schedule: every mon,tue,wed,thu,fri 09:15
  timezone: America/New_York
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb Updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a problem with cron.  It is a problem with your logs.  Notice it says `CST`.  We are on daylight savings time.  So it is really 8:15 CDT, which is 9:15 EDT.

At the top of your logs is a pulldown for the time that says, "no limit" or "last hour" or similar.  Change that to `Jump to time`, and you will get a time picker.  Modify the time picker, and it should change to CDT.  Seems a bit buggy.  May need to refresh, and/or delete all the query string props in the url to get it to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check that every entry in your `cron.yaml` has the appropriate `timezone`, and the timezones are spelled correctly.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref refers to https://wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zoneinfo_time_zones for timezones.